# How important is the quality of the content of 3D animations made for toddlers?

Tags: toddler, television

I am a mother with a children at 2 years old and I am looking for nursery rhymes  animations to share with my little one. In this question, my problem is expressed regarding the quality of the characters and story itself.

Are there any quality suggestions about the content?

Comment: Welcome to Parenting.SE, Adelina. Can you clarify this question: are you asking about the quality of the _animation work_ or the quality of the _content_? I did need to edit out the request for a list of favorite nursery rhymes (we don't do "list" questions, since literally everybody might have a different favorite: see [on-topic]) but if you can [edit] to give more detail about what you mean I will be happy to reopen your question. Thank you, and again, welcome!

Comment: Here's the rub: you will probably watch the cartoons too or hear them in the background, hundreds of times. Accept only quality you can stand.

Comment: If you don't think the quality is good enough to provide some value to your child, then pick a different program. In my humble opinion there's nothing wrong with screening young children's TV based on what the caregiver can stand to watch. For example, I cant stand Barney or the Tellytubbies. I just want to scream watching it. So we watch something else when I'm in the room.

Comment: Adelina; Don't stress about that...think of ALllllll the previous children who were born, and did fine, without any animation at all.

Comment: It's worth noting that too much screen time is [not considered good for children](http://www.npr.org/sections/ed/2014/08/28/343735856/kids-and-screen-time-what-does-the-research-say), regardless of the quality of the content.

Comment: I think there is another aspect to this... I'm not sure it is appropriate that toddler's view any artificial 3D animations. When I bought my children a 3DS for gaming it clearly specified that 3D features should be disabled for people under a certain age.

Comment: By 3D do you mean 3D requiring devices to see the dimensions separated, like a 3D movie where you wear glasses? Or do you mean like 3D animated cartoons like Frozen and Toy Story as opposed to older hand animated cartoons? I know youtube is littered with trash 3D cartoons and I have yet to figure out how to bury youtube beyond their reach, but I'm right there with you. I can't imagine how anyone would benefit from watching some of the BS out there

Answer (score 1):

The [American Association of Pediatricians recommend](https://www.aap.org/en-us/advocacy-and-policy/aap-health-initiatives/Pages/Media-and-Children.aspx) that children under 2 years old have zero screen time, and that children over 2 have only have 1 or 2 hours per day of quality screen time.

Quality is partly subjective. Some things you may want to look out for are:

1) Positive behaviour.  Children sometimes copy poor behaviour. There is lots of anecdote about children [copying poor behaviour](http://www.mommyish.com/2013/07/31/parents-hate-caillou/).

2) Diversity and equality.  It's good to show confidant women, caring men, and so on.  Characters with disabilities give you the chance to talk about those with your child.

3) Age appropriate.  Sometimes you want your child to be learning things and to be challenged by what they watch.  Sometimes you just want them to relax and watch something fun.

4) Production Values. It's important for children to be able to hear what the characters are saying.

5) You might want to avoid advertising.

There is a lot of programming aimed at children, and most of it is terrible.